# Disable ransack gem searching all

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ransack

How to disable ransack gem to search all records in the first request?

I own thousands records and did not want them all to be loaded every time I access the page. I just want to display the search form.

```
def index
   @search = ransack_params
   @users = ransack_result
end

private
def ransack_params
  User.search(params[:q])
end

def ransack_result
  @search.result(distinct: false)
end
```

The output of my console shows the following:

```
Processing by UsersController#index as HTML Parameters: {"utf8"=>"✓", "q"=>{"name"=>""}, "button"=>""}
  Rendering users/index.html.erb within layouts/application
  User Load (0.5ms)  SELECT "users".* FROM "users"
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Can do it in two ways.

1 - Don't iterate through user results if params[:q] is blank. 
Search query isn't executed until you try to consume the records of the search results relation.

so you can do like following in your view

```
unless params[:q].blank?
  # @search.each do ...
end
```

2 - create an empty scope which generates no results

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
  scope :empty_results, -> { where(id: '-1000') }
end

def ransack_params
 if params[:q].blank?
   User.empty_results.search
 else
   User.search(params[:q])
 end
end
```